# how to fetch dynamic input text id of dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to fetch dynamic input text id of dynamically created textbox but the output it is showing is `undefined`

Here is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/VuwXn/1/

Output should be `Know my value`.

Please suggest some solutions. Badly trapped!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you referring jquery if you never really use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotes are the problem.
It has been simplified and working as below:

```
var variable="123";

function deleting(mynum){
    alert($("input[id='"+mynum+"']").val());
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= '<input type="button" value="Know my value" id="'+variable+'" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleting(' +variable + ')" />';
```

Answer (score 2):

I updated your fiddle to use jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/VuwXn/12/

```
var variable="123";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").html("<input type='button' id='"+variable+"' class='btn btn-danger' value='know my value'/>");
    $("#"+variable).click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```